# Break the Iframe

Tags: html, iframe, break

I have an iframe on a landing page and I want to break the frame upon the viewers submit. When the viewer goes to the second page the frame cuts the image on the page is there a way to break, if I don't control the iframed page submit button. Could i frame my own button over the existing and have it scripted to "push" both buttons one to break the frame and the other to carry to the second page? I would prefer to have script to break on submit but how would the page know when the button is pushed?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you control both the framed page and the page that contains the frame, and they're both within the same domain, you're probably not going to be able to do this.